# How do you know when a resume login attempt is being made or was completed?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

On the client:

1. Can you tell on page load whether a resume login attempt will be made?
2. Is there a hook for when the attempt returns? Can I listen for the right DDP message?

EDIT: Looks like `Meteor.userId()` is defined on page load when a resume login attempt will be made, which takes care of #1.

Comment: Maybe `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (attemptInfo) { ... })` can be useful. This must be placed in server. Inside of the function you can use `if (attemptInfo.type == 'resume') { ... }`. For further details see the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt)

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit to clarify that I'm concerned with client-side hooks.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you explain your use case?

Comment: I'm working on a package that generates OTP tokens for sending to the user in a link. When the user clicks the link, if the user does not successfully get resume-logged in, I want to `Meteor.call(restrictedLogin, otpToken)` that sets the userId on the connection. And if resume login was successful, I want to set `Meteor.connection.unrestricted = true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple solutions:

## Watch DDP on client

Unfortunately by the time the stream handler is called with the result of the login method, `Meteor.connection._methodInvokers` has been cleared – hence the search function. It would be nice if there was a different / more efficient way to know `resumeMethodId`. A few possibilities:

- Is it guaranteed to have id `"1"`?
- A hook that is called when Meteor decides to call login
- If `Meteor.connection._methodInvokers` were reactive, I could do an autorun that stops after the id is found.

.

```
resumeAttemptComplete = (success) ->
  console.log 'resumeAttemptComplete', success

resumeMethodId = null

searchForResumeMethodId = ->
  for id, invoker of Meteor.connection._methodInvokers
    sentMessage = invoker._message
    if sentMessage.method is 'login' and sentMessage.params[0].resume?
      resumeMethodId = id

if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.connection._stream.on 'message', (messageString) ->
    unless resumeMethodId
      searchForResumeMethodId()

    message = JSON.parse messageString

    if message.id is resumeMethodId and message.msg is 'result'
      resumeAttemptComplete !message.error
```

`_methodInvokers` definition: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/de74f2707ef34d1b9361784ecb4aa57803d34ae8/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L79-L83

## Server onLogin sends event to client

```
// server:

// map of connection ids -> publish function contexts
let onResumePublishers = {}

Meteor.publish('onResume', function () {
  onResumePublishers[this.connection.id] = this

  this.ready()

  this.onStop(() => {
    delete onResumePublishers[this.connection.id]
  })
})

let handleLoginEvent = function({connection, type}, loggedIn) {
  if (type === 'resume') {
    let publisher = onResumePublishers[connection.id]
    if (publisher)
      publisher.added('onResume', connection.id, {loggedIn}})
  }
}

Accounts.onLogin(function (loginAttempt) {
  handleLoginEvent(loginAttempt, true)
})

Accounts.onLoginFailure(function (loginAttempt) {
  handleLoginEvent(loginAttempt, false)
})

// client: 

let resumeExpires = new Date(localStorage.getItem('Meteor.loginTokenExpires'))
let resumeAttemptBeingMade = resumeExpires && resumeExpires > new Date()

let OnResume = new Mongo.Collection('onResume')

let onResumeSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('onResume')

OnResume.find(Meteor.connection.id).observeChanges(
  added(id, {loggedIn}) {
    onResumeSubscription.stop()
    onResumeAttemptCompleted(loggedIn)
  }
})

let onResumeAttemptCompleted = function(success) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check `Meteor.loggingIn()` .If you want to know if the user is trying to login or not . [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loggingin)

Comment: During a resume login, `loggingIn()` is never true, and `onLogin` isn't called on the client.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? By failure you mean login attempt with wrong password?

Comment: Mainly concerned with the resume case – if the token login succeeds, I want to set a field on the connection. If it fails, I want to call a certain method.